# htaccess and correct url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My problem is that I can't figure out why my htaccess doesn't work.

When I check FTP path it is /var/www/html/folder/subfolder/

Since I am running WP site and I need that subfolder to be accessible, so I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* ./index.php
```

I tried with adding `html` and of course removing `folder` but nothing is working.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't say what you are trying to achieve and what you get instead.

Comment: My url is www.domain.com/subfolder/ , now I can't access it with this, I get "Page not found" and I want to be accessible...

Answer (score 0):

If you have httpd 2.2.16 or above, you should use [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) instead of all those rewrite rules:

- Put a .htaccess inside the folder you wish to have redirects for
- Add `FallbackResource /index.php`
- Have cake.